# How Select Multiple Items from a Drop Down lists and insert multiple value to MYSQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have an html form that has a select list box from which you can select multiple values that come from the database.
I want to be able to select multiple values simultaneously, in the example here we can be able to select multiple email addresses at once by pressing the add button where I want to show with a comma separator, so when we choose an email address through the drop down list it will automatically be displayed in the input field 'To' such as: neymar@gmail.com, ronaldo@gmail.com, messi@gmail.com then the user can also delete the last email in the input by pressing the delete button, when the user has selected one email then I want email that has been selected is no longer available in this drop down list to avoid data redundancy.

last I want every email address that has been selected can be sent the same message content (insert multiple value to MYSQL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Dropdown with Multiple checkbox select with jQuery</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">


      <style>
      /* NOTE: The styles were added inline because Prefixfree needs access to your styles and they must be inlined if they are on local disk! */
      body {
  font: normal 14px/100% "Andale Mono", AndaleMono, monospace;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #374954;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

a {
  color: #fff;
}

.dropdown dd,
.dropdown dt {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.dropdown ul {
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
}

.dropdown dd {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown a,
.dropdown a:visited {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.dropdown dt a {
  background-color: #4F6877;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 20px 5px 10px;
  min-height: 25px;
  line-height: 24px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 0;
  width: 272px;
}

.dropdown dt a span,
.multiSel span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 3px 2px 0;
}

.dropdown dd ul {
  background-color: #4F6877;
  border: 0;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 2px 15px 2px 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  width: 280px;
  list-style: none;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.dropdown span.value {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown dd ul li a {
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown dd ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
}

button {
  background-color: #6BBE92;
  width: 302px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 5px 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
    </style>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <dl class="dropdown"> 

    <dt>
    <a href="#">
      <span class="hida">Select</span>    
      <p class="multiSel"></p>  
    </a>
    </dt>

    <dd>
        <div class="mutliSelect">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Apple" />Apple</li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Blackberry" />Blackberry</li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="HTC" />HTC</li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Sony Ericson" />Sony Ericson</li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Motorola" />Motorola</li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Nokia" />Nokia</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </dd>
  <button>Filter</button>
</dl>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>



    <script  src="js/index.js"></script>




</body>

</html>
```